# Zend return as array

Tags: arrays, zend-framework

I want to select a specific column from the table, and return the results as a simple array. I have the following code

```
$select = $this->select();
$select = $select->from($this,array('DISTINCT(conversation_id)','conversation_id'))
                 ->where('user_id =?',$user_id);
return $this->fetchAll($select)->toArray();
```

the problem is, the returned result is 2D. So if I want to get the results, I have to go like `$result[0]['conversation_id']`. How can I just get it so that I only have to type `$result[i]`?

Thanks

Comment: Why use the array, why not just use the object: `$result->conversation_id`, just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the following line of code

```
return $this->fetchRow($select)->toArray();
```

Comment: `return $this->fetchAll($select)->current()->toArray();` should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$select = $this->select();
$select = $select->from($this,array('DISTINCT(conversation_id)'))
                 ->where('user_id =?',$user_id);

$fetchedData = $this->fetchAll($select);

$dataArray = array();
foreach($fetchedData as $data)
{
   $dataArray[] = $data->conversation_id;
}
return $dataArray;
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, I thought there might be a way to do this without this?